# mongorestore failure: error writing file "/var/lib/mongodb"

Tags: mongodb, restore, mongodb-3.0

I want sync my server db with my local db;

- dump db

  > mongodump --db [db name]
- copy dump folder into my local
- restore dump on my local

  > mongorestore --db [db name] [dump folder path]

I have 4 dbs I can do this successfully for 3 of them but I got

```
mongorestore error: failure writing file /var/lib/mongodb
```

when I restore 4th db

There is enough room on the file system. I restarted the server and repeated the process and I don't get this error anymore. However, sometimes I get:

```
failed: restore error: cohortV5.orders: 
error restoring from dump/cohortV5/orders.bson: insertion error: EOF
```

and sometimes I get:

```
Failed: restore error: cohortV5.orders: error creating indexes for cohortV5.orders: 
createIndex error: no reachable servers
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally after two days, I found the answer, I get this error because of lack of memory. You need to add more memory if you work with big collection.

Comment: How did you add more memory?

Comment: What memory? RAM or disk ?

Comment: You need to add RAM. I was running mongo on Amazon t2.small instance, I upgrade the instance to t2.large with 8GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Some collections are too large to be restored and the error message is "`reading bson input: unexpected EOF`". Sometimes, the error message is `insertion error: unexpected EOF`

A workaround for this is that restore exclude the collection with issues, and then start restoring the collections with issue.

A PR was made today to add support for collection exclusion now. Hopefully mongo team would merge this and release soon. (`https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/issues/48`)

If you need the feature right away, try `https://github.com/soleo/mongo-tools` , and build with branch `TOOLS-976` .

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any one is still wondering how to get it done without upgrading ram:

Try

> --batchSize=10

along with the mongorestore command.
This will not load the whole document into the ram rather in batches

more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142673/mongo3-0-restore-fails-with-error-failed-restore-error-insertion-error-eof